# Export SQLite database to phone folders

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to collect data on an Android Phone, for which I am writing an app. The data is succesfully stored on a local SQLite database, but I am having great difficulty with exporting the SQLite database to a file that I can access from the phone itself. I have asked for both Read and Write permission on Android and they are granted. I have also tried to copy the database to different folders, without success.

```cs
private void ExportData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.Copy(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "database.db3"), 
           Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "allData.db3"));
}
```

How can I copy my .db3 file to accessible folders on the Android Device?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows

Comment: Hope this link may be helpful:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/0448269e-9dc5-4320-88a0-641ae0d01d1f/how-i-can-copy-my-sqlite-database-from-device-to-pc?forum=xamarinforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to export data from the app storage onto your SD-card:

```cs
private void ExportData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "databasename.db3");
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    var fileCopyName = string.Format("/sdcard/Database_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-tt}.db", DateTime.Now);
    File.WriteAllBytes(fileCopyName, bytes);
}
```

It requires write permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```cs
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```